# removeClass does not work while `css` method works

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have font awesome icon which i want to change via jquery. 
i have added a class `js-toggler` to it. when i use 
`$(this).find('.js-toggler').css("color", "red");` it works but when i use 
`$(this).find('.js-toggler').removeClass('fa-angle-double-down');` it does not work. 
the svg element is like this.

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-angle-double-down fa-w-10 js-toggler" style="font-size: 12px; padding-right: 5px; color: red;" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="angle-double-down" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M143 256.3L7 120.3c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l22.6-22.6c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l96.4 96.4 96.4-96.4c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0L313 86.3c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9l-136 136c-9.4 9.5-24.6 9.5-34 .1zm34 192l136-136c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6 0-33.9l-22.6-22.6c-9.4-9.4-24.6-9.4-33.9 0L160 352.1l-96.4-96.4c-9.4-9.4-24.6-9.4-33.9 0L7 278.3c-9.4 9.4-9.4 24.6 0 33.9l136 136c9.4 9.5 24.6 9.5 34 .1z"></path></svg>
```

what is wrong with this?

**edit**

the `svg` element is created by the font awesome dynamically from `i` so I guess something related to dynamically created content?

the jquery code

```
 $("#subject_contents>ul>li>a").on('click',function(e){
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('ul').hide('slow'); $(this).parent('li').children('ul').toggle('slow');
    $(this).find('.js-toggler').removeClass('fa-angle-double-down');

    e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Comment: its working fine, show your full jquery code to find the issues

Comment: @AnfathHifans code updated

Comment: please update the #subject_contents html code.. some part

Comment: Can you post a working demo? Like Codepen or jsFiddle?

Comment: the contents are a bit sensitive and editing will take time and modify the actual contents. so sorry for that.. :(

Comment: Then maybe some part of the HTML??